# Android JSON Parse

Tags: android, json

I have this json response:

```
[{"id":"1","cat":"A","pic":"false","sector":"1"},{"id":"2","cat":"B","pic":"true","sector":"2"}]
```

I need to parse it on android.

I have trying follow code:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
JSONArray jsonArray = obj.getJSONArray("");
JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);

Log.d("ID -> ", jsonObject.getString("id"));
Log.d("CAT -> ", jsonObject.getString("cat"));
```

But it doesnt work.

If my result will be:

```
{ "data":[{"id":"1","cat":"A","pic":"false","sector":"1"},{"id":"2","cat":"B","pic":"true","sector":"2"}]}
```

And I modify the code in:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = obj.getJSONArray("data");
```

It works.

How Can I parse It considered my first json response (without "data")

Thank you.

Comment: try JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response); and then something like for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length; i++) {
 JSONObject obj = jsonArray[i]; // maybe its jsonArray.get[i]; 
}

Comment: `new JSONObject(response);` why? `obj.getJSONArray("");` what do you think this does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use next code:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);

Log.d("ID -> ", jsonObject.getString("id"));
Log.d("CAT -> ", jsonObject.getString("cat"));
```

Because you have not an object in json, but an array, so you should create array instead of object. And thats why your modification works. Because in modified code "data" is an object (JSONObject)

Comment: and this is the better version of what I was trying to say

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(string_of_json_array);
for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject row = array.getJSONObject(i);
    id = row.getInt("id");
    pic = row.getString("pic");
}
```

Or you can just use Gson Library. Just create your pojo classes

```
public class Data{
     int id;
     String cat;
     String pic;
     String sector;

     //setter and getter
}
```

then,

```
List<Data> datas = gson.fromJson(string_of_json_array, new TypeToken<List<Data>>(){}.getType());
for(Data item: datas){
     String pic = item.getPic();
}
```

Comment: Hi, i have try your code but i have error: 'cannot referenced from a static context'.
`JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
List<Data> datas = Gson.fromJson(response, new TypeToken<List<Data>>(){}.getType());` the error is ref to 'response'