# Parsing string array from JSON object

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, arraylist

It might be too easy but I just cannot find a solution to this. How can I directly parse the `string` `array` out of the `JSON` object?

For example,

```
json = {"names":["John", "Alex", "David"]}
```

I cannot do `json.getJSONArray("names")` since it doesn't return a `string` `array`.

Comment: please check my answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android JSON parse this, how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674939/android-json-parse-this-how) or this :: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43529022/android-json-parse

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the data as a json array and the loop through it to create a list

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("{names:['1','2','3']}");
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("names");

List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
     names.add(jsonArray.getString(i));
}
System.out.println(names);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this my friend

```
try 
{

  JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject("Your json string");
  JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObj .getJSONArray("names");

   for(int i=0;i<jsonArray .length();i++)
   {
      String name= jsonArray.getString(i);
      Log.i("..........",""+name);
      // loop and add it to array or arraylist
   }
}catch(Exception e)
{
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this buddy, you will get the result in an array of strings.

```
    String json = "{\"names\":[\"John\", \"Alex\", \"David\"]}";
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("names");
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        list.add(jsonArray.getString(i));
    }
    String[] stringArray = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this function

```
public void ParseJsonArray(json){
try {
//if you have 1 column in json array
        JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray("names"); 
        int count = 0;

//if you have more columns      
        while (count<jsonArray.length()){

            JSONObject JO = jsonArray.getJSONObject(count);
            String s1 = JO.getString("column1");
            String s2 = JO.getString("column2");
            String s3 = JO.getString("column3");           
            count++;        }``

    String StrFinal = jsonArray;

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  }
    }
```